# Sticky side div with Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm having trouble making a side div sticky with Bootstrap 5.  I added `position-sticky` but that doesn't work although it does work for the top div that I also want to be sticky.  If I add `fixed-top` or `sticky-top` to the side div it just makes the div's height expand to the full size of the parent container which is not what I want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Title
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="layout-wrapper layout-content-navbar">
        <div class="layout-container">
            <div class="layout-page">
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
                        <div id="divMain">
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="card card-action mb-4 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="card-header align-items-center position-sticky fixed-top" style="background:white;">
                                        <h5 class="card-action-title mb-0">Title</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                <div class="position-sticky">
                                                    <div style="border:1px solid black;min-height:500px;">
                                                        I WANT THIS DIV TO BE STICKY
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parent height as `fit-content`, even you append more elements in the parent, it will also auto size itself. You can run the code snippet below to check if this is what you desire.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Title
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="layout-wrapper layout-content-navbar">
        <div class="layout-container">
            <div class="layout-page">
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
                        <div id="divMain">
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="card card-action mb-4 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="card-header align-items-center position-sticky fixed-top" style="background:white;">
                                        <h5 class="card-action-title mb-0">Title</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-3" style="position: sticky;top: 60px;height: fit-content;">
                                                <div class="position-sticky">
                                                    <div style="border:1px solid black;min-height:500px;">
                                                        I WANT THIS DIV TO BE STICKY
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                                <h5>Data</h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works although in my actual page I had to change the top value so I'd like it if that wasn't a static value (i.e. 60px in this example).  Also, I can scroll past the top of the div which shouldn't be allowed.